# Yii2 user identity gets null after login

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a Yii2 application in which I am authenticating user from third party API and once user is authenticated then I login the user and set identity and everything works fine. But as I navigate to any other page user identity gets null and user becomes Guest user.

Here is my login form:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use app\components\RestBehavior;
use app\models\web\LoginIdentity;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\helpers\VarDumper;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $company_id;
    public $companies=[];
    public $token;

    private $_user = false;


    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            RestBehavior::class
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email', 'password','company_id'], 'required'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 0);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = LoginIdentity::findUser($this->attributes);
        }
        return $this->_user;
    }

}
```

Here is my custom LoginIdentity class:

```
<?php

namespace app\models\web;

use app\components\RestBehavior;
use \Yii;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\VarDumper;

class LoginIdentity extends \yii\base\BaseObject implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $resource_id;
    public $token;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            RestBehavior::class
        ];
    }

    public static function findUser($params)
    {
        if(!empty(Yii::$app->user->identity))
        {
            return new static([
                'resource_id'=>self::getId(),
                'token'=>self::getAuthKey()
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            Yii::$app->controller->sendPOST('/login',$params);
            if(Yii::$app->response->statusCode===200)
            {
                $response=Json::decode(Yii::$app->response->data);
                $identity=new static([
                    'resource_id'=>$response['resource']['resource_id'],
                    'token'=>$response['token']
                ]);
                Yii::$app->session->set('resource_id',$response['resource']['resource_id']);
                Yii::$app->session->set('token',$response['token']);
                return $identity;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        $session=Yii::$app->session;
        if(!empty($session['resource_id'])&&!empty($session['token']))
        {
            return new static([
                'resource_id'=>$session['resource_id'],
                'token'=>$session['token']
            ]);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @param \Lcobucci\JWT\Token $token
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->resource_id;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
    }
}
```

Very strangely, the whole code works fine on my local computer i.e on localhost. But on server user get's logged in but logs out as he visits any new authenticated route. I have checked server's /var/lib/php/sessions folder, the session gets saved properly, so there are no permission issues.
Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here? Why it is working on my local computer and not remotely.
Thank you.

Comment: *But as I navigate to any other page user identity gets null and user becomes Guest user. ... Very strangely, the whole code works fine on my local computer i.e on localhost. But on server user get's logged in but logs out as he visits any new authenticated route.* So you only have this problem at the server? Then it must be just the server then if it works fine at your local pc?

Comment: There is a reason why you have to implement the functions specified by `\yii\web\IdentityInterface`. The reason its not working is probably because you didnt implement those functions. Im assuming Yii calls `findByUsername` to set the LoginIdentity. But you dont return anything there, so its interpreted as null.

Answer (score 1):

This was not related to Yii2 or Identity class implementation. The code was correct in every sense. The reason was that my server had `cookie_secure` set to true meaning that session could only be established on SSL but I was trying to login on insecure origin i.e http.
Also my site was working on SSL but as page loaded it turned to Not Secure or http because of invalid favicon path.
So firefox browser showed in console that cookie is rejected by the server when client is running on HTTP while Chrome's console was silent what was happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hammad for the answer, no other gave me a real solution, but I solved it in "web.php" configuration file, just changing  parameter 'secure' => true for false. The reason was that I used http instead of https (no SSL), the I use this temporary solution:

```
'session' => [
 'cookieParams' => [
            'secure' => false,
    ],
],
```